# Is allowing self contained xss on anchor elements safe (just blacklist javascript: properly)?

Tags: security, anchor, xss, data-uri

I know this is not a good idea for other elements and attributes, but for`<a href=>`it seems javascript: is the only scheme which can lead to true xss.

So is it safe to allow this ?
The only thing I coudn’t figure is if a flash file loaded with a data: ᴜʀɪ would keep the same origin of the site.

Comment: [Enumerating badness](http://www.ranum.com/security/computer_security/editorials/dumb/) is a bad idea in general. Browsers or plugins can add new protocols you're not aware of. For example older versions of IE supported vbscript in addition to javascript. Who says that browsers will never add a new one?

Comment: @CodesInChaos : I consider a single example of cross site scripting by using a currently available protocol on href= of`<a>`would be the definite answer.

Comment: In fact I found a sanitizer in that case. Their reply was it’s a completely safe practice. I asked this question to know if they’re wrong.

Comment: You could try `vbscript:` in older versions of internet explorer.

Comment: @CodesInChaos : yes but ɪᴇ is only 5% of their site traffic *(60% for chrome)*.  This pretty exclude older versions of ɪᴇ.

Comment: You could also try variants of `javascript:`. Different casing. Html encoding some letters or the `:`,...

Comment: @CodesInChaos : No they use nokogumbo along escapeutils. Their is no way of escaping *(several years of vulnerability corrections on that type of vector)*. The point of the question is to find something by what is explicitly allowed *(every protocols on href of anchor except javascript:)* and would affect a large part of their traffic. I would be very glad if you find a string that would exit unescaped after being submitted to [escapeutils](https://github.com/brianmario/escape_utils), but I know this won’t happen :‑).

Comment: Do you have a sandbox where I could test this sanitizer?

Comment: @CodesInChaos : This would need to be further discussed out of public channels in that case. I suggest writing a memo to ytrezq *(my account)* on [freenode](irc://chat.freenode.net:7000) in order to exchange e‑mail addresses out of spambots.

Comment: @CodesInChaos : I couldn’t found documentation about it. Which was the last internet explorer version to support`vbscript:`? Does it was supported everywhere a ᴜʀɪ can be used ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, allowing all protocols on the href element of anchor tags is
perfectly safe as long as the javascript: scheme is properly
blacklisted. There are no plugins that would allow to escape this behaviour.

Comment: No the content of href is controlled it’s protocols that aren’t. Also I already told their is nokogumbo. If nokogumbo can’t parse something then web browsers will do the same. The question is if a protocol available on recent browsers can enable xss ? All protocols are allowed. But there is no way javascript: would not pass [escapeutils](https://github.com/brianmario/escape_utils). Also Google chrome won’t let your example working in the case it would pass the parser *(I tried it)*.

Comment: No, javascript: within href is the only "known" way to reaching out Javascript interpreter of modern browers.

Comment: Then you could have simply answered : “Yes, allowing all protocols on the href element of anchor tags is perfectly safe as long as the javascript: scheme is properly blacklisted. There are no plugins that would allow to escape this behaviour” I would have accepted it.

Comment: Oh I forgot this is called self-contained xss with the data uri :‑).

Comment: Concerning your example, I recognize`https://www.google.com/%22%20onmouseover%3D%22alert%281%29`isn’t stripped nor escaped, but is there a way to make this work when quotes are automatically added to attributes values ?